# Uploading documents to a server using XQL/exist-db

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db

**APP Structure**

```
NiC
| upload.xq
| upload.html
| controller.xql
| assignments.html (a lot of files are in the main dir, which is probably not good)
| templates/page.html
| inReview/
| data/all the xml files currently in the database
| images/all the images currently in the db
| modules/app.xql
| modules/view.xql
```

Not all the files are here, but just some that are relevant and to give a flavor.

**New discovery and problem as it now stands**

I have been trying to get this uploader to work, and I've been stymied at every turn--BUT, I think it is finally working. However, it works in a very weird way, and I don't know why. Not knowing why it works this way and not another way is driving me crazy, and it will cause other problems down the line. So, I'm hoping someone can shed some light!

I'm basically hacking together something new from pieces of the sample Shakespeare archive in eXist-db. So, the structure of my whole app is virtually the same as the ship-with demo. That having been said:

**in page.html, which templates the whole look of the page and provides the header/navigation information:**

I have added a link to the navigation that goes to an upload page:

```
<li><a href="../upload.html">Contribute</a></li>
```

**upload.html:**

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="templates:surround?with=templates/page.html&amp;at=main">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.xql">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Upload an XML File for Review:</legend>
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <button id="f-btn-upload" name="f-btn-upload" value="true" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

**upload.xql:**

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $collection := '/db/apps/NiC/inReview/'
let $filename := request:get-uploaded-file-name('file')

(: make sure you use the right user permissions that has write access to this collection :)
let $login := xmldb:login($collection, 'username', 'superstrongpassword')
let $store := xmldb:store($collection, $filename, request:get-uploaded-file-data('file'))


return
<results>
   <message>File {$filename} has been stored at collection={$collection}.</message>
</results>
```

**All of this works, somehow. But the weird thing is in the controller.xql:**

Here's the relevant bit:

```
else if ($exist:resource = ("search.html", "form1.html", "demo-queries.html", "search-help.html", "about-NiC.html", "assignments.html", "success.html", "upload.html")) then
    (: the html page is run through view.xql to expand templates :)
    (: question: 11/2017 why if upload.html is noted here does the URL need to be relative to ../upload.html from page.html, though others don't? :)
    <dispatch xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
        <forward url="{$exist:controller}/{$exist:resource}">
            <set-header name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache"/>
        </forward>
        <view>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
        </view>
        <error-handler>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/error-page.html" method="get"/>
            <forward url="{$exist:controller}/modules/view.xql"/>
        </error-handler>
    </dispatch>
```

If in page.html I use just the link "upload.html" as the controller would seem to require (upload.html is in the same place and doing the same kind of thing in general that the other pages are, like assignments.html and so on) it doesn't work. I get the SAX exception error/content not allowed in prolog. The other pages are accessible, and the URL resolution is working as expected. But if the link is "../upload.html," the page is accessible and the upload works as I want it to.

**So my question is this: why?** Why can't I just use upload.html as the path, trusting the controller to do what it does? Why do I have to gerrymander a solution with the relative path?

Argh!

Comment: What does this have to do with XSLT or XQuery?

Comment: All of the elements are working together in exist-db, with XQL as a base--if it's not relevant here, can you suggest where to put it?

Comment: The question seems on-topic for SO, @Tonya, though probably more information will be needed before it can be answered.  My comment was about the tags you've applied: I don't see any XSLT (though I do now see the XQuery).

Comment: Thanks, John-- I removed the irrelevant tag.

Comment: I would suggest logging the value of `request:get-uploaded-file-data('file')` so that you can see what your form is really sending you.

Comment: I've seen information about problems in the XML file prolog, and I've checked that file repeatedly--unless they're hidden somehow, the XML file I'm trying to upload is well-formed with a proper header.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `request:get-uploaded-file-data()` is `xs:base64Binary*` while `xmldb:store()` expects "either a node, an xs:string, a Java file object or an xs:anyURI" (from the function documentation).
So you have to pipe the result through `util:binary-to-string()` first like

```
xmldb:store($collection, $filename, util:binary-to-string(request:get-uploaded-file-data('file')))
```

The error you see is because `xmldb:store()` throws an XPathException if unsuccessful.

Comment: So, I went back to another version of the uploader that DOESN'T call an app and gets to it by pointing to a standalone page in exist-db; this one worked, upload and all! I did a few more diagnostic tests by trial and error, and it seems that the problem is in the controller.xql file. Basically, I can get it to work, but only under certain circumstances that don't make sense to me. I will edit the question and hopefully someone can shed light on it! THANK YOU, Peter!

Answer (score 0):

So just to clarify your app structure is?

```
yourapp
| modules/upload.xq
| templates/page.html
| upload.html
| other1.html
| controller.xql
```

Do your other1.html files also call .xq modules? The controller handles .html and .xq files differently, so to go from modules/upload.xq you need to use a relative path step `../` to reach upload.html.

That being said, you are not alone in often being dumbfunded by the templating system's opinion on where things are at the moment :)

Comment: My app structure--would be very helpful, wouldn't it? I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Looking at your app structure I think my answer still stands. the controller.xq does one thing for files ending in .xq and another for files ending in .html. upload.html calls upload.xq on the same level, but they are in the parent directory of the wrapping page.html hence the path step. The other html don't have forms calling .xq files and hence go straight to the page.html wherever it is defined in the controller.